# Rails Flash Notice Via Ajax after completed method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, flash

I want to have a flash notice sent back to my view via ajax when my controller successfully completed an  uploaded file. However I don't know exactly how to handle the response from the server. What I have below is what I believe is very close to what I want but it's not quite working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

My Controller

```
def import
    begin
      Thread.new do
        Order.import(params[:file])
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
      end
    rescue
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Invalid CSV file format."
    end
    format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "Here is my flash notice" }
end
```

My Ajax Javascript

```
$(function() {

  var bar = $('.bar');
  var percent = $('.percent');
  var status = $('#status');

  $('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
      status.empty();
      var percentVal = '0%';
      bar.width(percentVal);
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
      bar.width(percentVal);
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
      status.html(xhr); //I think I need to change this but not sure what to
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def import
    begin
      Thread.new do
        Order.import(params[:file])
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
      end
    rescue
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Invalid CSV file format."
    end
     @notice = "Here is my flash notice"
end

$(function() {

  var bar = $('.bar');
  var percent = $('.percent');
  var status = $('#status');

  $('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
      status.empty();
      var percentVal = '0%';
      bar.width(percentVal);
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
      bar.width(percentVal);
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(response) {
       // replace the response in the div which displays notice
       status.html(response)
          }
  });
});
```

Comment: I am getting a internal server error 500. "ArgumentError in OrdersController#import too few arguments" in both your code and mine. If I redirect it literally gives me a copy of the webpage in the webpage but otherwise it causing a internal server error. Would you happen to know why?